# Which one is faster in MySQL? COUNT(id) or counting the result rows?

Tags: mysql, select, count, mariadb

I need to calculate the total rows in a huge table in MySQL. I'm writing a code with PHP and PDO in 2 forms. Please let me know which one could be faster? Using COUNT() function, or calculating the total returned rows?

**Method 1:**

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM tbl_users";
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array());
$rows = $q->rowCount();
```

**Method 2:**

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) as c FROM tbl_users";
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array());
$result = $q->fetch();
$rows = $result['c'];
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Depends on `COUNT(id)` value. If it is large then you will loose on output rowset sending to client stage. Anycase must be tested.

Comment: @Akina Easy to test. I have no doubt about the outcome on a large table. On a small table, the difference could have been imperceptible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting all the rows will require a transfer of the entire table data to the client. That's way more expensive than having mysql count the rows.

Comment: Furthermore, use `COUNT(*)`, not `COUNT(id)`.